# why the current directory not the target\classes?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

Using maven for a project say myproject

it has the following myproject\src and myproject\target, and all the class and resources are copied to myproject\target\classes.

However i found the user.dir or current dir is still myproject, why not myproject\target\classes, how to change the current dir to myproject\target\classes?

Comment: how are you executing your code?

Comment: If my understanding to your question is correct, then by running mvn clean install/mvn install/mvn compile, myproject/target/classes directory should be created or you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because maven always runs things in the working directory of the pom.xml, unless you configure it differently (which i think you can do in the surefire plugin which is what runs test cases).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get class folder path,you can following this code :

```
    String path  = YourClassName.class.getResource("").getPath();
```